# Show zero value when no data available in date sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two columns `sale_date` and `amount`:

```
sale_date     amount
-------------------
05/01/2014    400
05/02/2014    350
05/04/2014    430
.
.
```

I want the output to include a value of zero for `amount` if there are no sales for a particular date.

Desired output:

```
sale_date    amount
-------------------
05/01/2014    400
05/02/2014    350
05/03/2014      0
05/04/2014    430
.
.
```

Comment: you don't have to mention SQL Server in the title and 3 times in the question when you've tagged it with [SQL-Server]

Answer (score 2):

Consider this is your table

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(sale_date DATE, AMOUNT NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT '05/01/2014',   400
UNION ALL
SELECT '05/02/2014',    350
UNION ALL
SELECT '05/04/2014',    430
```

I have written the logic inside query

```
 DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE
 SELECT @MAXDATE = MAX(sale_date) FROM #TEMP

; WITH  CTE as
 (
     -- Select minimum date
     SELECT MIN(sale_date) as DATES
     FROM #TEMP    
     UNION ALL
     -- Increments month recursively till maximum date
     SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATES)
     FROM    CTE C1     
     WHERE   DATES < @MAXDATE
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT DATES,ISNULL(T1.AMOUNT ,0)AMOUNT
 FROM    CTE C1
 LEFT JOIN #TEMP T1 ON C1.DATES=T1.sale_date
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20677/1) to view result